# Unexpected mix of '||' and '&&' when using babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs

I am trying to build and publish a package to `npm` and I am using babel. But when its building, its showing me this warning:

> Line 1:    'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict
>
> Line 23:  Unexpected mix of '||' and '&&'                no-mixed-operators

Here's my method:

```
function required(value) {
  if (
    value === null ||
    value === undefined ||
    ("string" === typeof value && value.trim().length === 0) ||
    value.length === 0
  )
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

And here's how its converting:

```
function required(value) {
  if (value === null || value === undefined || "string" === typeof value && value.trim().length === 0 || value.length === 0) return false;
  return true;
}
```

I'ts removing `()` inside that `"string" === typeof value && value.trim().length === 0`, and its doing that inside every `if` `else` block

Here's my `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function(api){
    api.cache(true);

    const presets = [ "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react" ];
    const plugins = [ ];

    return {
        presets,
        plugins
    };
}
```

and here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepublishOnly": "babel ./src --out-dir ./dist -s inline"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How are you building ? What linter write those warnings ?

Comment: That message is likely coming from [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-mixed-operators). The question is why are you linting the compiled files? I would expect a lot more errors there, as they don't need to conform to coding standards, as long as the semantics are correct.

Comment: @VLAZ why would you expect more errors?

Comment: @ErtanHasani as I said, the compiled output does not need to conform to coding guidelines and Babel would just compile to something that semantically does the same as the input code. Once it does that, it could produce code that doesn't conform to the linter rules and you shouldn't expect otherwise but indeed assume it would spit out non-conforming code.

Comment: @VLAZ oh ok, i get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Babel is right here: parentheses aren't needed because of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`.

And a linter is right to say that this code is unreadable.

But the output of Babel isn't meant for your human eyes or a linter, it's for the browser.

Don't lint the ouput of Babel. The bug is in your build chain.

Side note: you can replace

```
if (a) return false;
return true;
```

with

```
return !a;
```

Comment: "Don't lint the ouput of Babel. The bug is in your build chain." Yeah that sounds like a valid point Thanks to you I realized that I probably messed some things a little up^^